# Swift Check Conformance Using `is` Versus Type Casing

Tags: swift, performance

If I wanted to check if a variable conforms to a protocol there are two ways to do it:

```
protocol Computer { }
struct Mac: Computer { }

let device = Mac()

device is Computer // option 1
(device as? Computer) != nil // option 2
```

From a pure performance POV which option is faster and by how much? Let's imagine we don't need the casted value we just want to know if it conforms. I would imagine the first option is faster, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Xcode comes with *Instruments,* a perfect tool to test your hypothesis ...

Comment: Such a simple operation shouldn't have performance implications in most cases, so I don't see any reason for even considering safe casting and then a `nil` check if you don't actually need the casted value. Simply use `is` and don't try to do premature optimization.

Comment: Hypothetically, suppose `(device as? Computer) != nil` was faster. How much faster would it need to be for you to feel justified replacing something as simple as `device is Computer` with something as nasty as `(device as? Computer) != nil`?

Comment: It was more of a curiosity question. I'm sure in the real world I would be hard pressed to come up with a case where it would matter.

Comment: you could indeed use instrumentals, write a loop which executes the line a million times and check how long it took

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a quick test and the performance difference is negligent. It's not a perfect way to test, but I used the following playground code:

```
import Cocoa

func executionTimeInterval(block: () -> Void) -> CFTimeInterval {
    let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
    block()
    return CACurrentMediaTime() - start
}

protocol Computer {}
struct Mac: Computer {}

// Mark as `Any` in case the compiler optimises the fact that the checks will always be true
let device: Any = Mac()

let iterations = 10000

var cumulativeTime = CFTimeInterval(0)
for _ in 0..<iterations {
    cumulativeTime += executionTimeInterval {
        _ = device is Computer
    }
}
cumulativeTime / CFTimeInterval(iterations) // option1

cumulativeTime = 0
for _ in 0..<iterations {
    cumulativeTime += executionTimeInterval {
        _ = (device as? Computer) != nil
    }
}
cumulativeTime / CFTimeInterval(iterations) // option2
```

Comment: Thanks for the test! I got almost identical result. Even when switching the second test to assignment and then a check I got only a 2x difference.

Comment: By the way, with full optimizations the `_ = device is Computer` part will be probably removed completely. This is not so easy to check. Testing performance in playgrounds is a big problem by itself.

Comment: You really *can't* test performance in Playgrounds. Like, at all.

Comment: @Alexander I ran it in a regular program and same results. I tried both with and without optimisations and you could see that those calls get optimised out (there's a proper term for that, but can't remember it).